# what causes duplicate symbols linking error in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

What are the causes of duplicate symbol errors, I understand that objective c doesn't have package scope but what exactly causes it.

E.x. extern variables which have the same name, what else causes duplicate symbols ? Take for example a class "foobar" which is in a static library which is then imported into another xcode project having the same name "foobar", will that cause duplicate symbols error?

Provided below is a list of duplicate symbols error that I get in one of the projects

```
duplicate symbol _new_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser_init in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser_init in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser.prefix_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser.attributeCount_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser.nspCounts_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser_class_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser.attributes_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser.error_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser.reader_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser.processNsp_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser.location_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser.elementStack_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser.nspStack_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser.depth_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser.encoding_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser.type_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser.standalone_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser.name_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser.isWhitespace_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser.relaxed_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser.unresolved_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser.degenerated_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser.version__ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlParser.namespace__ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlParser.o)
duplicate symbol _new_OrgKxml2IoKXmlSerializer_init in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgKxml2IoKXmlSerializer_init in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlSerializer in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlSerializer in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlSerializer.indent_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlSerializer.nspCounts_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgKxml2IoKXmlSerializer_class_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlSerializer.writer_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlSerializer.elementStack_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlSerializer.nspStack_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlSerializer.depth_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlSerializer.encoding_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlSerializer.pending_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlSerializer.unicode_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgKxml2IoKXmlSerializer.auto__ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(KXmlSerializer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParser in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParser in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParser__initialized in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParser_class_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParser_FEATURE_REPORT_NAMESPACE_ATTRIBUTES in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParser_FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParser_FEATURE_VALIDATION in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParser_FEATURE_PROCESS_DOCDECL in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParser_NO_NAMESPACE in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParser.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParser.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserException in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserException.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserException.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserException in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserException.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserException.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_EHTYPE_$_OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserException in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserException.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserException.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserException.row_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserException.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserException.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserException_class_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserException.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserException.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserException.column_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserException.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserException.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserException.detail_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserException.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserException.o)
duplicate symbol _new_OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserException_initWithNSString_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserException.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserException.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserException_initWithNSString_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserException.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserException.o)
duplicate symbol _new_OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserException_initWithNSString_withOrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParser_withJavaLangThrowable_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserException.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserException.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserException_initWithNSString_withOrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParser_withJavaLangThrowable_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserException.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserException.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserFactory in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserFactory in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
duplicate symbol _new_OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserFactory_init in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserFactory_init in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserFactory_newInstance in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserFactory_class_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserFactory_newInstanceWithNSString_withIOSClass_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserFactory.serializerClasses_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserFactory.parserClasses_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserFactory.features_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserFactory.classNamesLocation_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParserFactory_PROPERTY_NAME in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlPullParserFactory.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_OrgXmlpullV1XmlSerializer in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlSerializer.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlSerializer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_OrgXmlpullV1XmlSerializer in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlSerializer.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlSerializer.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1XmlSerializer_class_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(XmlSerializer.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(XmlSerializer.o)
duplicate symbol _new_OrgXmlpullV1Sax2Driver_init in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(Driver.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(Driver.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1Sax2Driver_init in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(Driver.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(Driver.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_OrgXmlpullV1Sax2Driver in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(Driver.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(Driver.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_OrgXmlpullV1Sax2Driver in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(Driver.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(Driver.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1Sax2Driver_class_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(Driver.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(Driver.o)
duplicate symbol _new_OrgXmlpullV1Sax2Driver_initWithOrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParser_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(Driver.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(Driver.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1Sax2Driver_initWithOrgXmlpullV1XmlPullParser_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(Driver.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(Driver.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgXmlpullV1Sax2Driver.contentHandler_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(Driver.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(Driver.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgXmlpullV1Sax2Driver.errorHandler_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(Driver.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(Driver.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgXmlpullV1Sax2Driver.pp_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(Driver.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(Driver.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_OrgXmlpullV1Sax2Driver.systemId_ in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(Driver.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(Driver.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1Sax2Driver_DECLARATION_HANDLER_PROPERTY in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(Driver.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(Driver.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1Sax2Driver_LEXICAL_HANDLER_PROPERTY in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(Driver.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(Driver.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1Sax2Driver_NAMESPACE_PREFIXES_FEATURE in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(Driver.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(Driver.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1Sax2Driver_NAMESPACES_FEATURE in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(Driver.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(Driver.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1Sax2Driver_VALIDATION_FEATURE in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(Driver.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(Driver.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1Sax2Driver_APACHE_DYNAMIC_VALIDATION_FEATURE in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(Driver.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(Driver.o)
duplicate symbol _OrgXmlpullV1Sax2Driver_APACHE_SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FEATURE in:
/Users/sam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomLib-frpqbpntkpegnvbwtkxxyhtzuuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lib.a(Driver.o)
/Users/Codes/libs/lib/libjre_emul.a(Driver.o)
ld: 94 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Yes, That also causing duplicate error. If some files with same name available in your project. Some times that happens that you included two third party library and by chance both have same classes name then also it gives error. Or one of two is including other library than also. like I have socketIO library and MindMeld Framework in that MIndMeld is including SocketIO library so I was not able to use both in one project.

Comment: will same named public functions/methods in different headers also cause duplicate symbols?

Comment: No, That will not cause that but same named global variables declared in two different files may cause this. Would you please share error logs and code where this error occurred?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with the error log for your perusal

Comment: XML parser library causing this. Please check once that folder contains two library for same purpose: one of them is not referenced in your project but may be placed on your project directory.

Comment: Actually both use the same XML library, although one is a contained in a static library libjre_emul and the other one is contained within a project that is added as a dependency to the top level project! I am unsure if it's the name of the classes that is conflicting or the symbol names?

Comment: You have same case as mine was. So you have to either delete your library which project contains or contact libjre_emul library developer and ask them to give you version without it Or you can find alternative library for same purpose but both together won't work.